# Emacs AUCTeX keeping focus to the source buffer after runinng TeX-command-run-all

Tags: emacs, auctex

I am using Emacs AUCTeX with pdf-tools. When I compile my tex file with `C-c C-a`, i.e., run TeX-command-run-all command. When it is finished, my cursor moves to the generated pdf file. I would like my cursor to stay focused on my .tex file buffer. How do I achieve this?

Comment: Probably that is the expected reaction: compile and go to pdf. Please add your emacs version, AUCTeX version and the OS.

Comment: I am using Emacs 26.1, macOS Mojave, AUCTeX 12.1.2.

Comment: No idea, but I learned to switch buffers in a split second with `C-x o` .

Comment: no problem with my init file http://ix.io/1KGv.